# Correcting a webhook: Zoho People to Freshbooks

Tags: xml, api, zoho

This is my first time posting on Stackoverflow so apologies if what I post is head-slappingly simple.

I've been trying to set-up a webhook between Zoho People and Freshbooks for the past few days. The aim is to push the email address and name of new employees from Zoho to Freshbooks. This data will populate a form emailed to the user inviting them to join me on Freshbooks as a contractor.

I've done this correctly as far as I can tell and Freshbooks and Zoho both say that the webhook is correct. They can't seem to work out why it isn't working.

The details set-up on Zoho People are:

URL to Notify - https://teachtutti.freshbooks.com/api/2.1/xml-in
Method - Post 
Form Name - Music Teacher (this is where the email address and name are taken from originally by Zoho)
Entity Parameters:
   - Parameter name = email  |  Parameter value = ${email_address}
Parameters in the User Defined Format:
   - Parameter name - XML 
   - Value Description:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->  
<request method="contractor.create">  
     <contractor>  
        <name>${First_name} ${Last_name}</name>  
        <email>${email_address}</email> <!--Required-->  
        <task_id>190354</task_id> <!--Required-->  
        <projects>  
         <!-- Assign new contractors to specific projects using project_id -->  
            <project>  
                <project_id>49537</project_id>  
            </project>  
        </projects>  
    </contractor>  
</request>
```

Custom Parameters:
- authtoken = 27a8ad5004154bf19f0a6805ee8154a6
- task_id = 190354
- project_id = 49537

The preview URL that is created from all the above information is https://teachtutti.freshbooks.com/api/2.1/xml-in?email=${email_address}&XML=&authtoken=27a8ad5004154bf19f0a6805ee8154a6&task_id=190354&project_id=49537

If you type in the above URL, you'll receive the following reply:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<response xmlns="http://www.freshbooks.com/api/" status="fail">
<error>Your XML is not formatted correctly.</error>
<code>40010</code>
</response>
```

I have done everything I can think of to fix this. The project ID, task ID, authentication token, and URL to notify are all correct. I'm completely stumped!

If someone could help me fix this, I'd be eternally grateful! For what it's worth, Zoho seems to think the problem stems at Freshbooks end because they have confirmed that the data is being sent to Freshbooks. Annoyingly, I tried to go around the problem by creating the webhook at Freshbooks end, only to find out that the contractor.create api call isn't available from their end...